# How fast is Perl's smartmatch operator when searching for a scalar in an array?

Tags: perl, smartmatch

I want to repeatedly search for values in an array that does not change.

So far, I have been doing it this way: I put the values in a hash (so I have an array and a hash with essentially the same contents) and I search the hash using `exists`.

I don't like having two different variables (the array and the hash) that both store the same thing; however, the hash is much faster for searching.

I found out that there is a `~~` (smartmatch) operator in Perl 5.10. How efficient is it when searching for a scalar in an array?

Comment: I believe that "smart match" is still going to have to search the entire array every time, which means each time you search it's going to be about O(N).  Whereas a search for a hash is O(1).

Comment: Paul: well, that's the point of my question.... does smart match go through the array every time, or is it... smarter? :)

Comment: A smart match doesn't have to search the entire array. Someone might implement a smart match like that, but Perl 5.12 doesn't. That still doesn't make it better speed-wise than a hash, though, even in the best case.

Comment: Paul Tomblin: "Search" in a hash is not O(1). It is O(log n).

Comment: @alexandr: If by "search" you (and Paul) mean "lookup", then it is, by all practical standards, O(1). Depending on what the implementation does on hash collisions, it may be O(log(n)) or O(n) in special circumstances. As far as I am aware, Perl has various tricks up its sleeve to prevent that, so let me repeat: For all practical purposes, hash lookup IS O(1).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to search for a single scalar in an array, you can use [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-Util)'s `first` subroutine. It stops as soon as it knows the answer. I don't expect this to be faster than a hash lookup *if you already have the hash*, but when you consider creating the hash and having it in memory, it might be more convenient for you to just search the array you already have.

As for the smarts of the smart-match operator, if you want to see how smart it is, test it. :)

There are at least three cases you want to examine. The worst case is that every element you want to find is at the end. The best case is that every element you want to find is at the beginning. The likely case is that the elements you want to find average out to being in the middle.

Now, before I start this benchmark, I expect that if the smart match can short circuit (and it can; its documented in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)), that the best case times will stay the same despite the array size, while the other ones get increasingly worse. If it can't short circuit and has to scan the entire array every time, there should be no difference in the times because every case involves the same amount of work.

Here's a benchmark:

```
#!perl
use 5.12.2;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my @hits = qw(A B C);
my @base = qw(one two three four five six) x ( $ARGV[0] || 1 );

my @at_end       = ( @base, @hits );
my @at_beginning = ( @hits, @base );

my @in_middle = @base;
splice @in_middle, int( @in_middle / 2 ), 0, @hits;

my @random = @base;
foreach my $item ( @hits ) {
    my $index = int rand @random;
    splice @random, $index, 0, $item;
    }

sub count {
    my( $hits, $candidates ) = @_;

    my $count;
    foreach ( @$hits ) { when( $candidates ) { $count++ } }
    $count;
    }

cmpthese(-5, {
    hits_beginning => sub { my $count = count( \@hits, \@at_beginning ) },
    hits_end       => sub { my $count = count( \@hits, \@at_end ) },
    hits_middle    => sub { my $count = count( \@hits, \@in_middle ) },
    hits_random    => sub { my $count = count( \@hits, \@random ) },
    control        => sub { my $count = count( [], [] ) },
  }
);
```

Here's how the various parts did. Note that this is a logarithmic plot on both axes, so the slopes of the plunging lines aren't as close as they look:

[image: Smart match speed]

So, it looks like the smart match operator is a bit smart, but that doesn't really help you because you still might have to scan the entire array. You probably don't know ahead of time where you'll find your elements. I expect a hash will perform the same as the best case smart match, even if you have to give up some memory for it.

---

Okay, so the smart match being smart times two is great, but the real question is "Should I use it?". The alternative is a hash lookup, and it's been bugging me that I haven't considered that case.

As with any benchmark, I start off thinking about what the results might be before I actually test them. I expect that if I already have the hash, looking up a value is going to be lightning fast. That case isn't a problem. I'm more interested in the case where I don't have the hash yet. How quickly can I make the hash and lookup a key? I expect that to perform not so well, but is it still better than the worst case smart match?

Before you see the benchmark, though, remember that there's almost never enough information about which technique you should use just by looking at the numbers. The context of the problem selects the best technique, not the fastest, contextless micro-benchmark. Consider a couple of cases that would select different techniques:

- You have one array you will search repeatedly
- You always get a new array that you only need to search once
- You get very large arrays but have limited memory

Now, keeping those in mind, I add to my previous program:

```
my %old_hash = map {$_,1} @in_middle; 

cmpthese(-5, {
    ...,
    new_hash       => sub { 
        my %h = map {$_,1} @in_middle; 
        my $count = 0;
        foreach ( @hits ) { $count++ if exists $h{$_} }
        $count;
        },
    old_hash       => sub { 
        my $count = 0;
        foreach ( @hits ) { $count++ if exists $old_hash{$_} }
        $count;
        },
    control_hash   => sub { 
        my $count = 0;
        foreach ( @hits ) { $count++ }
        $count;
        },
    }
);
```

Here's the plot. The colors are a bit difficult to distinguish. The lowest line there is the case where you have to create the hash any time you want to search it. That's pretty poor. The highest two (green) lines are the control for the hash (no hash actually there) and the existing hash lookup. This is a log/log plot; those two cases are faster than even the smart match control (which just calls a subroutine).

[image: Smart match v. hash]

There are a few other things to note. The lines for the "random" case are a bit different. That's understandable because each benchmark (so, once per array scale run) randomly places the hit elements in the candidate array. Some runs put them a bit earlier and some a bit later, but since I only make the `@random` array once per run of the entire program, they move around a bit. That means that the bumps in the line aren't significant. If I tried all positions and averaged, I expect that "random" line to be the same as the "middle" line.

Now, looking at these results, I'd say that a smart-match is much faster in its worst case than the hash lookup is in its worst case. That makes sense. To create a hash, I have to visit every element of the array and also make the hash, which is a lot of copying. There's no copying with the smart match.

Here's a further case I won't examine though. When does the hash become better than the smart match? That is, when does the overhead of creating the hash spread out enough over repeated searches that the hash is the better choice?

Comment: I just used Numbers (from iWork). I don't think they are that nice, but it's what I had handy.

Answer (score 10):

Fast for small numbers of potential matches, but not faster than the hash. Hashes are really the right tool for testing set membership. Since hash access is O(log n) and smartmatch on an array is still O(n) linear scan (albeit short-circuiting, unlike grep), with larger numbers of values in the allowed matches, smartmatch gets relatively worse.

### Benchmark code (matching against 3 values):

```
#!perl
use 5.12.0;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my @hits = qw(one two three);
my @candidates = qw(one two three four five six); # 50% hit rate
my %hash;
@hash{@hits} = ();

sub count_hits_hash {
  my $count = 0;
  for (@_) {
    $count++ if exists $hash{$_};
  }
  $count;
}

sub count_hits_smartmatch {
  my $count = 0;
  for (@_) {
    $count++ when @hits;
  }
  $count;
}

say count_hits_hash(@candidates);
say count_hits_smartmatch(@candidates);

cmpthese(-5, {
    hash => sub { count_hits_hash((@candidates) x 1000) },
    smartmatch => sub { count_hits_smartmatch((@candidates) x 1000) },
  }
);
```

### Benchmark results:

```
             Rate smartmatch       hash
smartmatch  404/s         --       -65%
hash       1144/s       183%         --
```

Comment: This is with a small candidates array. I bet that if the array was 25+ items, there would be a much more significant difference.

Comment: The size of candidates makes no real difference to the relative performance. Did you mean the size of hits?

Comment: I re-jiggered the benchmark to try it with different candidate array sizes and use different positions of the hits in the candidate array. It makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 9):

The "smart" in "smart match" isn't about the searching.  It's about doing the right thing at the right time based on context.

The question of whether it's faster to loop through an array or index into a hash is something you'd have to benchmark, but in general, it'd have to be a pretty small array to be quicker to skim through than indexing into a hash.