# Searching unsorted array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array with... lets say 100 elements. I want to check to see if any of the elements matches a particular string. For example:

@array = ('red','white','blue');

I also want to know if the array contains the string 'white' as one of the elements. 
**I know how to do this with a foreach loop and comparing each element**, but... is there an easier (faster) way than looping through the whole array?

-Thanks

Comment: Because it's unsorted, any method you find is going to involve searching the whole array, so it's not going to be faster than looping through it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951812/how-fast-is-perls-smart-match-operator-for-searching-scalar-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be any faster than looping, but you can use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) within Perl.

```
$ perl -e "@array = ('red','white','blue'); print grep(/^white$/, @array);"
white
```

Comment: That does seem easier, I don't really mind the speed but simplicity of code is always nice. -Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Perl 5.10 and higher, [smart match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail):

```
say 'found' if 'white' ~~ @array;
```

For pre-5.10, [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{any}; 
print "found" if any { 'white' eq $_ } @array;
```

These short circuit - if a match is found there is no need to traverse the whole array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep` as:

```
@array = ('red','white','blue');
$key = 'white';
if (grep { $_ eq $key } @array) {
        print $key.' found';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for also posting about "grep" but also thank-you for showing an example of how I would use it within my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to search the array many times, it would be worth while to build a hash table of your array data:

```
my %array_data = map { $array[$_] => $_ } 0..$#array;
my $search_term = 'white';
if (defined $array_data{$search_term}) {
    print "'$search_term' was found at array index $array_data{$search_term}\n";
}
```