# if at least one element of array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Maybe my question is really easy, but I would like to know the best way and efficient one.

Let's we have an array of strings and we want to compare it with another string.
say,

```
my @array = {"hi","bye","you","shadow", "hi"}
```

Now I want to check if at least one element of the array equals `hi` then there is some condition.
May I know your idea about it. I know that within a `for` loop one could do it easily, but Would you would suggest as a good one?

Comment: Use `grep` on the array?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
my @array = qw (hi bye you shadow hi);
my $hi_count = scalar(grep {$_ eq 'hi'} @array);
print $hi_count;
```

This will print `2` as there are two words that equal `hi`.

Comment: `any` from [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#any) is better for large arrays since it will return as soon as a match is found; `grep` will loop through every single array element no matter what.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Would you please send your comment as a answer?

Comment: @Royeh No, because it has already been used in answers on at least 3 duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/720482/176646, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4570650/176646, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2860226/176646. No reason to add it here, too.